# How to send data inside an intent without external storage

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am trying to send data to a ACTION_VIEW or ACTION_SEND intent without writing that data to a file.

Most intents want a Uri, which is usually based on a file path or url like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getFilesDir(), TEMP_FILE_NAME));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I would prefer that the data I am sharing with an intent not be viewable by everyone on external storage. Internal storage (as in the example above) is not granted to called intents (meaning that a pdf viewer cannot see files in my app's private space).

Diane Hackborne alludes to data being able to be copied in the intent here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be9b069ca8906417#

But I have not found any other data on how this would happen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what form/size your data takes, but probably the simplest option is to include the data as an "extra" on the `Intent`.

[Extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) can be of various different types, including most Java primitives (`String`, `int`, `double` etc) and `Bundle`s and `ArrayList`s.

If you have your own class structure, you can also implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and include instances of your own classes as extras.

However, I would say that if your data is large in volume, passing it around in memory with the `Intent` is probably not the best idea. If this is the case, you may just have to bite the bullet and temporarily write the data to storage for the duration of the call and clear it up when your calling `Activity`/`Service` regains focus.

Comment: I agree with you on using extras for your own intents. How would this work for ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_SEND for viewing and sending via third parties though?  What was Diane saying in the link I posted?

Comment: I believe Dianne was referring to extras in her post. If you are attempting to invoke a third party Activity/Service with your `Intent`, then to a certain extent your options are limited as that third party component will expect to receive data in a certain way (which should be documented). If the third party component expects to receive a `Uri` then you will have to either make use of internal/external storage or come up with your own `ContentProvider` implementation (e.g. backed by a Sqlite database)

Comment: Okay, so just to verify, there really is not a secure way to pass a file to those generic intents without writing it to shared storage or creating a content provider that is open to everyone?

Comment: May I ask what type of data you are attempting to pass with your intent (I may be able to give you a better answer if I know more)?

Comment: Specifically a PDF, but because they're generic intents, let's say something that has a mime type and an associated chunk of data.

Comment: Not done this before, but you could create a custom `ContentProvider` which returns a `Cursor` from its `query()` method containing the mime type (as a string) and the data (as a blob). The `MatrixCursor` implementation should allow you to build the cursor you want and pass in the file contents as a byte array.

Comment: Any idea if you can limit the apps that can read a content provider?

Comment: Not really. Android's Intent mechanism is deliberately designed to ensure very loose coupling between applications. One app isn't supposed to have knowledge of another specific app, rather it uses an Intent to request that _any_ supporting app carry out the desired function. So by providing your data via an Intent you are by definition making it available to any app which supports your Intent. I'd appreciate an upvote or two if any of this is helpful :-)